# SharePoint online - User profile country information

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

I need to refer the user "Country" property from user profile. 
Currently the call to `_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|*accountname*` does not return country property.

But for each user in contact information, country value is available :
[image]

So is there any way to sync this country information to user profile ?

Answer (score 1):

For getting specific property you can use

```
_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='PropertyToGet')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|abc@xyz'
```

Comment: but i need country specific information. i am  able to get other properties.

Comment: Find the property name for country/region and pass it in the REST API call as explained in the answer

Comment: Yes it finds all the Person Properties, but Country is an extended user profile property. Here is a list of Person Properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx#bk_PersonProperties